# How to convert a pen drive to a dongle?

Tags: security, dongle, software-protection

I have a desktop application I've written in c#. I only want users with a license dongle to be able to use the software. I checked, there are companies that provide this facility but I find them expensive.

Is there a way I can turn an old pendrive into a dongle so it doesn't show in the file explorer, but the software can read from it ??

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with a normal pendrive. You would have to change the firmware of the pendrive controller.